# Issue occurs when we have same multiple targets (images) and we allow simultaneously 2 objects

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

Issue occurs when we have same multiple targets (images) and we allow simultaneously 2 objects.
Even when One image is tracked, system loads 2 objects.

i need to load only one object at this time with same image marker 
need to track different marker simultaneously

Following is the link of video that shows issue:

[Please see this video](https://youtu.be/31ohXbcaOzQ)

Comment: You need to describe your issue a little and provide the code that is creating the issue. There is no way for anyone to help otherwise.

Comment: here i s no code require to do this this use vuforia sdk please see video thats the problem